# PHP shmop issues

Tags: php, shared-memory

I am using shmop to do some simple server throttling by keeping track of the number of current server connections and rejecting new ones once the number is above a certain threshold value.  Essentially, when a script starts up it increments a shared counter variable in shmop and decrements it in a registered shutdown function.

This works like a charm and shmop_x seems to be really easy to use.  The size of the memory block I am using is small, 16 bytes.

However, given that I have never used shmop before I thought I should check - are there any gotchas, race conditions etc to be aware of when using shmop?